# How to add a new viewResover named ‘MultiViewResover’ in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

in spring boot add a viewResover named ‘MultiViewResover’ in spring boot.
in controller if i return 'ftl:/freemarker/test' then MultiViewResover will use FreeMarkerViewResolver and find /freemarker/test.ftl

if i return 'th:/thymeleaf/test' then MultiViewResover will use ThymeleafViewResolverand find /freemarker/test.html

here is my code

Application.java

```
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.addInitializers();
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Autowired
    MultiViewResover resover;

    @Bean(name = "viewResover")
    public MultiViewResover getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafView.class);

        FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setPrefix("");
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");

        Map<String, ViewResolver> resolvers = new HashedMap();
        resolvers.put("jsp",internalResourceViewResolver);
        resolvers.put("th",thymeleafViewResolver);
        resolvers.put("ftl",freeMarkerViewResolver);

        resover.setResolvers(resolvers);
        return resover;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

MultiViewResover.java

```
@Component   
public class MultiViewResover implements ViewResolver {

    private static Map<String, ViewResolver> resolvers ;

    /**
     * 默认视图类型为jsp视图
     */
    private static final String DEFAULT_VIEW_TYPE = "jsp";

    @Override
    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
        int n = viewName.lastIndexOf(":"); // 获取
        String suffix = MultiViewResover.DEFAULT_VIEW_TYPE;
        // 默认使用jsp视图
        if (n != -1) {
            // 有的话截取:前面的字符串 这里一般是jsp,ftl,vm,th与Map resolvers中的key匹配
            suffix = viewName.substring(0, n);
            // 取:后面的部分 那时真正的资源名.比如我们要使用hello.jsp 那viewName就应该是jsp:hello
            viewName = viewName.substring(n+1);
        }
        // 根据:前面的字符串去获取托管的视图解析类对象
        ViewResolver resolver = resolvers.get(suffix);

        if (resolver != null)
            return resolver.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);
        return null;
    }

    public Map<String, ViewResolver> getResolvers() {
        return resolvers;
    }

    public void setResolvers(Map<String, ViewResolver> resolvers) {
        this.resolvers = resolvers;
    }

}
```

MyController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test1",name = "test return th view",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test1(){
        return thView("login");
    }
public ModelAndView thView(String viewPath){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("th:"+viewPath);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

but when i run this application it throw an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver@40e94dde] does not run in an ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.getApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.applyLifecycleMethods(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:513)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:156)
    at me.luger.core.mvc.controller.MultiViewResover.resolveViewName(MultiViewResover.java:51)
    at me.luger.core.mvc.controller.MultiViewResover$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8118b2de.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at me.luger.core.log.aspect.ControllerLogAspect.doAround(ControllerLogAspect.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at me.luger.core.mvc.controller.MultiViewResover$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7c3b2b9.resolveViewName(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.getCandidateViews(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:299)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.resolveViewName(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1296)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1234)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`InternalResourceViewResolver` requires the application context, as it extends `WebApplicationObjectSupport`. So you need to create it as a Bean so it gets injected with it.

Note that I don't see the point of this `MultiViewResolver`, as you're trying to achieve something already supported by Spring. You can already add multiple view resolvers and order them while keeping them independent. Your implementation ties all the templating engines together and overlooks the fact that some view resolvers (like the `InternalResourceViewResolver`) will throw exceptions if they can't resolve a view and that won't give view another chance to resolve that view with another resolver.